# React functional component with non-JSX class has an internal array returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

- See Update Below

I'm writing some classes and functions for a library I'm creating and I've hit a wall.

I can't find any information on why a non-JSX class has an initialized array but, when used in a react functional function it's undefined.

I've create a codesandbox with a few of the test's I've tried so far to include:

- Normal Initialization
- useRef initialization
- useState Initialization
- static instance Initialization

All of these initializations are logging that the array is undefined in the class function call.

[image: Edit blazing-dust-noh2m]

The codesandbox contains the following code:

```js
//App.js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import testClass, { TestClass } from "./TestClass";

export default function App() {
  //Testing normal initialization
  const test = new TestClass();
  console.log("test init");
  //test.printList();

  //Testing useRef
  const testRef = useRef(new TestClass());
  console.log("testRef");
  //testRef.current.printList();

  //Testing useState
  const [testState, setTestState] = useState(new TestClass());
  console.log("testState");
  //testState.printList();

  //Testing static instance
  //console.log("static instance");
  //testClass.printList();

  //The problem is that the list logs undefined instead of [] (initialized)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={test.printList} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        ClickMe (Normal Initialization)
      </button>

      <button onClick={testRef.current.printList} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        ClickMe (Ref Initialization)
      </button>

      <button onClick={testState?.printList} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        ClickMe (State Initilization)
      </button>

      <button onClick={testClass.printList} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
        ClickMe (static instance Initilization)
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
//TestClass.js
export class TestClass {
  list = [];

  constructor() {
    //this says it's initialized
    console.log(this.list);
  }

  printList() {
    //this is undefined
    console.log(this.list);
  }

  static get instance() {
    return testClass;
  }
}

const testClass = new TestClass();

export default testClass;
```

*Update

I've updated the codesandbox. Ian brought my attention to my functional calls inside the buttons and I've updated that area.

With the new buttons I'm getting back defined list like intended.

However, my question still remains why is the array undefined / when calling e.g.

```js
export class TestClass {
  list = [];

  constructor() {
    //this says it's initialized
    //console.log(this.list);
  }

  printList() {
    console.log("function", this.list);
  }

  printList2 = () => {
    console.log("const", this.list);
  };

  static get instance() {
    return testClass;
  }
}

const testClass = new TestClass();

export default testClass;
```

```js
{/* log -> "function" undefined (function still being called?) */}
<button onClick={test.printList} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
  ClickMe (Normal Initialization)
</button>

{/* log -> "const" [] (as expected)*/}
<button onClick={test.printList2} style={{ margin: 10 }}>
  ClickMe (Normal Initialization)
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you assign `printList` to `onClick` prop of button.

```
<button onClick={test.printList} />
```

This would change the `this` context binding to `window`, and `window.list` is undefined, thus the problem.

Correct way to do it:

```
// 1. Inline arrow function
<button onClick={() => test.printList()} />
// 2. Bind `this` context explicitly 
<button onClick={test.printList.bind(test)} />
// 3. Use arrow function at declaring the method in class
class TestClass {
  printList = () => {
    console.log(this.list)
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, yes that answers my question. I realized that I had my calls incorrect just now but, I was still confused why it was undefined. That makes since that it's changing this context binding to the window. Thanks hackape. Do you know where I could find more information on how the binding works?

Comment: Try search for “understand JS this keyword”, there’re plenty of posts on the topic. To me this is a concept I’ve learned over the year, cannot recall any particular resource that’s especially helpful, so cannot give recommendations, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you `console.log` in the constructor, you're actually referencing the list as an attribute of the window object via `this`, since you define `list` outside of your class constructor. What you should do instead is do `const list = []` inside the constructor. Only then will your class's `this` have access to `list`.

Comment: although this is incorrect you helped me to continue troubleshooting. I'll update my question. To define in the constructor I would use ```this.list = []```. Your answer helped me to realise that In the button onClick I had the wrong calls. I'll describe in the updated section of the question.

Comment: You don’t need to change how you declare `list` property, it’s totally valid syntax per ES spec. This answer is simply wrong.